# How can I list all files and symlinks in a compact view?

Tags: bash, ls

This is my setup in `/tmp/test/`

if I use `ls -l`

```
-rw-r--r--  1 rubo77 rubo77    0 Okt 21 04:15 a
-rw-r--r--  1 rubo77 rubo77    2 Okt 21 04:16 b
drwxr-xr-x  2 rubo77 rubo77 4,0K Okt 21 03:58 c
lrwxrwxrwx  1 rubo77 rubo77    1 Okt 21 03:57 d -> c
lrwxrwxrwx  1 rubo77 rubo77    1 Okt 21 03:58 e -> a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 rubo77 rubo77    2 Okt 21 03:59 f -> nofile
```

---

If I use just `ls` I see only the files without details:

```
a b c d e f
```

---

`ls -F` appends an indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries

```
a  b  c/  d@  e@  f@
```

---

**How can I achieve this display?**

```
a  b  c/  d->c/  e->a  f->nofile
```

Comment: lame answer that doesn't quite do what you want it to: `ls -l | grep "->"`. there's probably a way to get rid of the additional information, but I don't really feel like poking through the manpage right now.

Comment: I "poked" through the manpage and there seems to be no such option for `ls`. But maybe with another command?

Comment: I don't think this can be done in a compact way. Especially since since sometimes a link can point to a really long path to another file, and this would look odd: `a b c/ d->~/dev/kernel/net/wireless/mac80211/blah.c e->../../../dir/file f->e`. Furthermore, what if the link is pointing to another link; how is that handled? It may be worth scripting to you, but probably not a default put into `ls` or any other listing programs.

Comment: Not with `ls`. You'll have to do your own `stat` and `readlink` then your own formatting in columns (you could call `ls` to leverage the coloring).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple solution with some more information:

```
ls -hago | column
```

also interesting (but without the links shown):
This will show all files with human-readable sizes in columns:

```
ls -sh
```

**These commands will do the job:**

```
ls -lah | awk '{print $5, $9$10$11}' | column -t | column
```

or

```
ls -hago --color=no| sed 's/^[^ ][^ ]* *[^ ][^ ]* \( *[^ ][^ ]*\) ............/\1/' | column
```

with coloring it works too, but doesen't look so ordered:

```
if [ -t 1 ]; then color=yes; else color=no; fi
ls -hago --color="$color"| sed 's/^[^ ][^ ]* *[^ ][^ ]* \( *[^ ][^ ]*\) ............/\1/' | column
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

    ls -l | while read response
        do
            words=`echo $response | wc -w`      #count how many words are

            case "$words" in
                9) echo $response | cut -d " " -f9 # when file is not a symlink then the ouput prints only 9 fields
                    ;;
               11) echo $response | cut -d " " -f9-11 # when file is symlink its prints 11 fields indicating the target and symbol "->"
                   ;;
            esac
        done
```

Comment: this will show it like `test2 -> test` but only one line per file. I would like to see it compact as many files as fit in one line already

Comment: maybe we find a solution here.: [How do I echo a line with linebreak at the end at window border?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101908/how-do-i-echo-a-line-with-linebreak-at-the-end-at-window-border)

Comment: How can I use `column` to format the complete output in columns?

Answer (score 0):

If you buffer the output you can send it to `column` :

```
#!/bin/bash
TMP=/tmp/output-buffer
echo "">$TMP
ls -l | while read response
    do
        words=`echo $response | wc -w`

        case "$words" in
            9) echo $response | cut -d " " -f9 >>$TMP
                ;;
           11) echo $response | cut -d " " -f9-11 >>$TMP
               ;;
        esac
    done
cat $TMP | column
rm $TMP
```