# How do I echo a line with linebreak at the end at window border?

Tags: columns, output, text-formatting

I would like to echo a list all in one line, TAB separated (like `ls` does with files in one folder)

```
for i in one two some_are_very_long_stuff b c; do echo $i; done
```

will print one line per word:

```
one
two
some_are_very_long_stuff
b
c
```

instead I would like to break it, like `ls` without options does:

```
mkdir /tmp/test
cd /tmp/test
for i in one two some_are_very_long_stuff b c z; do touch $i; done
ls
```

will output

```
b  one                       two
c  some_are_very_long_stuff  z
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `columns` command from GNU `autogen`.

```
$ seq 60 | columns
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52
53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
```

With `zsh`, you can use `print -C`:

```
$ print -C4 {1..20}
1   6   11  16
2   7   12  17
3   8   13  18
4   9   14  19
5   10  15  20

$ print -aC4 {1..20}
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
9   10  11  12
13  14  15  16
17  18  19  20
```

And if you need to sort them first (like `ls` does):

```
$ print -oC4 {1..20}
1   14  19  5
10  15  2   6
11  16  20  7
12  17  3   8
13  18  4   9
```

Comment: There is no s in column.

Comment: @richard, we're not talking of the BSD `column`  command here (from `bsdmainutils` on Debian based systems), but of the GNU `columns` command (from GNU `autogen`).

Comment: ok. `Columns` is more powerful version of `column`, though I had to `apt-get install autogen`. `column -x` does the job for the simple case, the `-x` just changes the order from like first print example, to same as `columns`. So no spelling error, either will do.

Answer (score 0):

from the `echo` man page:

```
-n     do not output the trailing newline
-e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes
If -e is in effect, the following sequences are recognized:
   ...
   \t     horizontal tab
```

so this will do:

```
for i in one two some_are_very_long_stuff a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o; do 
   echo -en "$i\t";
done; echo
```

Comment: This will put it all on one line.

Comment: Yes, it is not perfect, but if the screen is narrow, it looks a bit more ordered with these tabs. `column` and `columns` is the better solution