# List only file size and name and symlinks

Tags: ls

When I use `ls -lah` I get lots of information for each file.

How can I get only the name and filesize?

Additionally I would like to keep the listing of symlinks with the arrow like

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 rubo77    rubo77       4 Nov 21 01:53 test2 -> test
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Selecting columns to print with awk

One method would be to parse the output of `ls`.

#### Example

```
$ ls -lah | awk '{print $9, $5}' | tail -5
.yEd 4.0K
.youtube-dl 4.0K
.zenmap 4.0K
.zshrc 32
zzzz 3.3K
```

By the way, you can clean up the output using `column`.

```
$ ls -lah | awk '{print $9, $5}' | column -t | tail -5
z                                                   4
.youtube-dl                                         4.0K
.zenmap                                             4.0K
.zshrc                                              32
zzzz                                                3.3K
```

#### Selecting columns to remove with awk

If you'd rather remove the other columns, while keeping others you can use this `awk` method to blank out the undesirable columns.

#### Example

```
$ ls -lah | awk '{$1=$2=$3=$4=$6=$7=$8=""}1' | tail -5
    4.0K    .youtube-dl
    4    z -> zzzz
    4.0K    .zenmap
    32    .zshrc
    3.3K    zzzz
```

#### Eventual solution

The OP came up with this chain of commands, using a mix of the examples from above.

```
$ ls -lah | awk '{print $5, $9$10$11}' | column -t | column 
...
4.0K  .gphoto              773   .rdebug_hist     4.0K  .youtube-dl
1.5K  .grip                4.0K  .rdesktop        4     z->zzzz
```

Comment: cool, if I use `ls -lah | awk '{print $5, $9$10$11}'|column` I get what I wanted

Comment: @rubo77 - see updates, for another method to blank out the unwanted columns too.

Comment: you should trim each line and sent that to `column`

Comment: Your awk strategy doesn't preserve alignment. The ones using column inclusion truncate file names containing spaces; the one with column removal doesn't have this defect. Also piping into another command suppresses the colors that many people use.

Comment: If you expect files with leading or trailing spaces you could use `ls -lahQ` to quote filenames instead

Comment: @slm: please add a symlink in your example

Comment: @rubo77 - yes I saw you tried that, I've added one.

Comment: if you add `| column -t | column` you get the right formatting back. This works best for me: `ls -lah | awk '{print $5, $9$10$11}' | column -t | column`

Answer (score 5):

From the man page:

> ```
>   -s, --size
>           print the allocated size of each file, in blocks
> ```

So for human-readable sizes:

```
ls -sh
```

Comment: I was looking for this to find a solution to [How can I list all files and symlinks in a compact view?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96908/how-can-i-list-all-files-and-symlinks-in-a-compact-view/101937#101937) so this looks promising, but it doesen't show the symlink targets as I was hoping, like ls -lah does. (I added this to the question)

Comment: if you want to see hidden files too, use `ls -ash`

Answer (score 4):

One quick and dirty way is to combine the output of `ls -lah` with a couple of other commands:

```
ls -lah | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5,9-
```

The `tr -s` command replaces multiple spaces with single spaces, and the `cut -d' ' -f5,9-` prints columns 5 and 9 (and beyond). The `9-` is required to account for additional space-separated columns produced by symlinks.

Comment: If I try to columnize that symlinks gets stretched at the arrow : `ls -lah | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5,9- | column -t | column`

Comment: Well your question doesn't say anything about printing in columns.

Comment: you are right, that was just related to my other question: [How can I list all files and symlinks in a compact view?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96908/how-can-i-list-all-files-and-symlinks-in-a-compact-view/101937#101937)

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get with `ls` only is to suppress the user and group columns with `ls -log`. If you want to go further, you can parse the output. Beware that the second column (the link count) has variable width. The following shell snippet takes care to preserve column alignment, copes with arbitrary file names (except newlines if they're passed literally), and displays the output in color (remove that part if you aren't running GNU coreutils).

```
if [ -t 1 ]; then color=yes; else color=no; fi
ls -h -log --color="$color" | sed 's/^[^ ][^ ]* *[^ ][^ ]* \( *[^ ][^ ]*\) ............/\1/'
```

Comment: Is it possible to get this columnized like ls without options does?

Comment: @rubo77 Columns don't play so well with displaying symlink targets, which tend to get pretty wide. If you really want it, [piping through `column`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96908/how-can-i-list-all-files-and-symlinks-in-a-compact-view) is the way to go.

Comment: This answer is also fine, you could use: `ls -halog --color=no | sed 's/^[^ ][^ ]* *[^ ][^ ]* \( *[^ ][^ ]*\) ............/\1/'|column`

Comment: but slm's answer with `awk` is easyer to remember